# Doctrine Jointure in criteria

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, criteria

I have 3 classes :

```
Class Question
{
    /**
     * @ORM\OneToMany(targetEntity="Answer", mappedBy="question")
     */
    private $answers;

   ...

    public function getAverage()
    {
        $sum = 0;

        foreach ($this->answers as $answer)
            $sum += $answer->getGrade();

        return $sum / $this->answers->count();
    }
}

class Answer
{
    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Question", inversedBy="answers")
     */
    private $question;

    /**
     * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="User")
     */
    private $user;

    private $grade;

    ...
}

class User
{
    ...

    private $username;
}
```

I'd like to be able to create Question::getAverage($username) like that :

```
public function getAverage($username)
{
    $criteria = Criteria::create()
        ->where(Criteria::expr()->eq("user.username", "$username"));

    $answers = $this->answer->matching($criteria);

    $sum = 0;
    foreach ($answer as $answer)
        $sum += $answer->getGrade();

    return $sum / $answers->getGrade();
}
```

But I get the following error: "Unrecognized field: user.username".

Could anyone help me? I was looking for making a jointure with criteria but I didn't find! (I know I can filter my answers by using an if condition inside of my foreach statement but it's not the way I'd like to do).

Thanks.

Vincent.

Answer (score 0):

Why you didn't use custom repository http://docs.doctrine-project.org/en/2.0.x/reference/working-with-objects.html#custom-repositories ?